# NSSet has no subscript members

Tags: swift, uitableview, nsset

I have a CoreData object that has an relationship that is `NSSet`. I'm trying to use this as my dataSource, but getting the following

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = playerTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell")! as UITableViewCell
    cell.textLabel?.text = self.game.players[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

How do I use my NSSet in a tableView and I believe this would be unordered so potentially different each time, so how could I order this set?

Comment: If you want to bring order to a set, then you should load the elements into an array.

Comment: @TimVermeulen Yes, i've started to look at this, it's second on my list. I guess I could order the CoreData objects by name into an array?

Comment: For instance, yeah.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `allObjects` to get an array from the set and sort the objects afterwards.

```
let orderedPlayers = (game.players!.allObjects as! [Player]).sort { $0.name < $1.name }
```

If you declare the set as native Swift type `Set<Player>` – CoreData supports also Swift types – you can even omit the type cast and `allObjects`:

```
let orderedPlayers = game.players!.sort { $0.name < $1.name }
```

Comment: Hey @vadian, when I turned the Set<> how can I use the indexPath.row in cellForItemAt. It gives an error like "Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'Set<Item>.Index"

Comment: A `Set` is unordered, better use an array as described in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it:

```
for player in game.players! {
        orderedPlayers.append(player as! Player)
    }
    orderedPlayers.sortInPlace({ $0.name < $1.name })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add subScript to `game` core data class like this:

```
subscript(index: Int) -> Player? {
    let descriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)
    let orderedPlayerArray = players?.sortedArray(using: [descriptor])
    let playerWhereIndex = orderedPlayerArray?[index]
    return playerWhereIndex as? Player
}
```